# Call with Post Method

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

From when I get result with SOAP call var_dump as follows:

## WSDL map

stdClass Object
    (
        [Sites] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 102728
                        [siteId] => 0
                    )

I would like to achieve call Sites array to display data:

## Post method call the SOAP Data

```
<?php 


$opts = array(
            'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
        );`enter code here`

// SOAP 1.2 client
$params = array (
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
    'verifypeer' => false, 
    'verifyhost' => false, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 
    "connection_timeout" => 180, 
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );

//disable wsdl cache 
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 


$client = new SoapClient("http://www.example.com?WSDL",$params);

$result1=$client->getSiteInfo();

$zone = $result1->Sites;
if(isset($_POST['rayat'])){
    echo $zone;
}
 else {


?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">

<input id="rayat" name="rayat" size="10" type="text" value=""  />
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>



    <?php 

    //$param = array('isbn'=>'0385503954');
    // define path to server application
    $opts = array(
                'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
            );

    // SOAP 1.2 client
    $params = array (
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
        'verifypeer' => false, 
        'verifyhost' => false, 
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
        'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 
        "connection_timeout" => 180, 
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );

    //disable wsdl cache 
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 

    $server = '';

     
    $client = new SoapClient("http://www.example.com?WSDL",$params);

    $result1=$client->getSiteInfo();
      
    $zone = $result1->Sites;
    if(isset($_POST['rayat'])){
        echo $zone;
    }
     else {
        

    ?>


    <form action="champ.php" method="post">

    <input id="rayat" name="rayat" size="10" type="text" value=""  />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>

    <?php
     }
     ?>
     




<?php
 }
 ?>


Above code give me result is 'Array'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SOAP results are an array of objects as your var_dump() is telling you. If you are saying that your SOAP call will always only return one result, you can cheat a little by doing something like:

```
    $zone = $result1->Sites;
    if(isset($_POST['rayat'])){
        echo 'ID: ' . $zone[0]->id . '<br>SiteID: ' . $zone[0]->siteid;
    } else {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

trying to get Search value, its giving no value!Please coorect me!

## WSDL

stdClass Object
    (
        [opsTrackerSites] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                       [managerName] => DECOMM-MGR, GC
                       [techName] => dectech
    )

```
<?php
    $opts = array(
                    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
                );


        $params = array (
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
            'verifypeer' => false, 
            'verifyhost' => false, 
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
            'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 
            "connection_timeout" => 180, 
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );

        //disable wsdl cache 
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 




        $client = new SoapClient("http://example.com?WSDL",$params);

        $result = $client->getSiteInfo();
        $zone = $result->Sites;
        $output = '';
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
            $searchq = $_POST['search'];
            $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
            $zone = $result->Sites;

            if($zone == ''){
                $output = 'There was no search results!';
            }
            else{
                 $output .= '<div>' .$zone->techName.''.$zone->managerName.'<div>';
                 echo $output;
        }}
?>
 <form action="champ.search.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for Contacts..."> 
             <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

$zone variable is an array, you cannot echo an array so you either have to loop through the array and echo each individual value or access the values directly as shown in the other answer.